# PackageReference Resolve Version Logic as API

Tags: msbuild, nuget, csproj, msbuild-15, packagereference

Is there any accessible API via an MSBuild task, target or otherwise that allows me to query what version of a NuGet package a given PackageReference will resolve (or has already resolved) to?

For example, if I have a csproj with

```
<PackageReference Include=“MyPkg” Version=“1.*”/>
```

And I have a custom target where I want to

```
<MyTarget>
  <GetVersionOfResolvedPackageReference Name=“MyPkg” OutputProperty=“IWantToKnowThis” /> <!— or something —>
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How NuGet resolves package dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution):

> When the NuGet restore process runs prior to a build, it resolves
>   dependencies first in memory, then writes the resulting graph to a
>   file called project.assets.json in the obj folder of a project using
>   PackageReference. MSBuild then reads this file and translates it into
>   a set of folders where potential references can be found, and then
>   adds them to the project tree in memory.

---

```
<#
.Synopsis
    Represents the method that
    returns the project.assets
    content as object.
#>
function Get-ProjectAssest([System.String]$Assest) {

    return (Get-Content $Assest | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json).value |
                                                   ConvertFrom-Json
}

Get-ChildItem -Path . 'project.assets.json' -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Get-ProjectAssest($_.FullName) } | ForEach-Object {

    # K = Package Identity
    # V = Package Version
    $_.libraries | ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties.Name } | Out-File 'PackageReference.ini' -Append 
}
```

---

This `PowerShell` script recursively parses directories to find `project.assets.json` and writes result in `PackageReference.ini` file. You can call script from MSBuild via [Exec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task) task and after that read file via [ReadLinesFromFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/readlinesfromfile-task) and performing further processing.

---

> **NOTE**: Represented script will be produce duplicates of `PackageReference` lines for multiple projects.